# Oracle sql subtring in case don't work

Tags: database, oracle

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT id,
       CASE
         WHEN com_column IS NULL
           THEN ''
         ELSE SUBSTR(com_column,0,50) || '...' 
       END AS ss 
  From Table;
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What means *dont work* any error message?

Comment: Expected CHAR obtained CLOB

Comment: This could be more simply rewritten as `case when com_column is not null then substr(com_column, 1, 50) || '...' end`. There is no such concept as an empty string (i.e. `''`) in Oracle - this is treated as NULL.

Comment: Do you want the result of the computation (which you aliased as `ss`) to be a CLOB or a VARCHAR2? It is more likely that it should be a VARCHAR2 - otherwise why would you truncate to 50 characters and adding ... at the end?  The solution you marked "correct" will produce a CLOB. To get a VARCHAR2 you have to wrap the SUBSTR() expression within `CAST ( ....   AS VARCHAR2(100)  )` or whatever length you desire for this calculated column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax seems basically correct,  as you can see

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'abcd' IS NULL THEN NULL 
       ELSE SUBSTR('abcd',0,50) ||'...' 
       END AS ss 
  FROM DUAL;
```

You should verify if com_column is in your table and if it's of correct datatype (`VARCHAR2`, `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, ...).

Anyway, in case of `NUMBER` datatype, Oracle should do implicit conversion.

Comment: com_column is VARCHAR2 so i dont know why simple quotes dosent work in that 'CASE WHEN'

Comment: try to write it again and/or to decompose your problem (eg. be sure that  
   SELECT ID, com_column FROM TABLE     works, then try SELECT id,com_column, SUBSTR(com_column,0,50) FROM TABLE and so on...)

Comment: I tried each detailed solution but it don't work together. Any way thanks Null works.

Comment: It should work ...CASE WHEN xx iS NULL THEN '' ... too, ie with single quotes instead of NULL.  The result for VARCHAR type would be the same (NULL).

Comment: @Adriano - `com_column` is VARCHAR2? **Are you sure**? That is very hard to believe, considering the error message you received. If the column is not CLOB, then it's unlikely the query you posted is EXACTLY the query you ran.

Comment: @etsa - there IS a significant difference between `NULL` and `''` in Oracle. In a CASE expression (or, similarly, in a set operation like UNION ALL), `NULL` is not given a data type; it can be followed by a NUMBER or a DATE expression, and the NULL will be cast to that later data type. On the other hand, `''` is specifically of VARCHAR2 data type; follow it with a date, or a CLOB, and you will get exactly the error the OP got. This is why `NULL` should be preferred to `''` in these cases, even in Oracle.

Comment: @mathguy  I agree with your clarification.